# How to copy files and add prefix at the same time?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command

I am not familiar with osx terminal command.

I have a java project containing many package.

Some classes have same name in different package.

I need to copy all of the class files into a directory, so I need to add 
corresponding package prefix on each files.

For example,  I have `root/com/example1/test.java` and `root/com/example2/test.java` two classes having the same name in different packages. I need to copy them into `root` directory and add prefix, making them become `example1.test.java` and `example2.test.java` in `root` directory.

How to do this using terminal command?

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with Java. If so, please remove the unnecessary parts of the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution is not perfect but it should do what you want (assuming I understood your question correctly):

Create a file `doCopy.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
origName=$1
newName=$(echo $origName | sed -e 's|/|.|g')
echo cp $origName $newName
```

Then make it executable and call it for each of your files:

```
chmod +x doCopy.sh
find root -type f -exec ./doCopy.sh {} \;
```

Please verify the commands that will be printed. If you are satisfied you can remove the `echo` from `doCopy.sh` and rerun the `find` to actually copy the files.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain the reason for the vote?